# Get real path with Expression Language

Tags: path, el, realpath

I have to get the real path of a **JSP**, and I have to do it with **Expression Language**. Then, I send the path in a **TagLib**.

I have found that :

```
<mytag:getstats rtexprvalue="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

But I have a warning on `rtexprvalue` saying it is *undefind* and another in the **EL** : `The declared exception IOException is not actually thrown by the method _elExpression15() from type 
 __2F_PrizeWheel_2F_WebContent_2F_stats_2E_jsp`.

The declaration of my **TagLib** in my **.tld** is as follow :

```
<tag>
    <name>getstats</name>
    <tag-class>connector.FileConnector</tag-class>
    <attribute>
        <name>name</name>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Maybe I do it totally wrong. So if you have a better solution, I'm interested :)

Comment: Why do you need an attribute to get the `contextPath`? You can use `pageContext` to get the `ServletRequest` and you can cast that to `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The warning is unrelated (seems to happen randomly)
- The "real path" is not the "context path"

What you are looking for is `${application.realPath}`

Comment: Do you know why does this warning appear? I get lots of them, that's really not helpful.